# How can I distinguish between transactions (send vs. receive)?

Tags: transaction-data, viewkey, balance, transfer

How can I distinguish between the transactions I sent and those that came to me?
If I decrypt the outputs using my view key and address in the amount field, I get balance / tx amount. But other fields are equal.
For example (using https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html),
tx sent by me:

```
This address doesn't own output 0 with pubkey: c9cab9f8d53eba51f00640d19ea4215632c1b94ed3df78cbc91fbe9bedd1dac8 for amount: Confidential
This address owns output        1 with pubkey: 9ae1f1843fa68489d532b9b77c6073a8a79fb4f9c3ba348ca42eed8f46290a89 for amount: 0.04322344

Total received: 0.04322344
```

If decrypted with the recipient address:

```
This address owns output        0 with pubkey: c9cab9f8d53eba51f00640d19ea4215632c1b94ed3df78cbc91fbe9bedd1dac8 for amount: 0.0001
This address doesn't own output 1 with pubkey: 9ae1f1843fa68489d532b9b77c6073a8a79fb4f9c3ba348ca42eed8f46290a89 for amount: Confidential

Total received: 0.0001
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about where your confusion stems?  Your example seems to indicate that you sent funds to yourself, so you received both 0.0432 and 0.0001, each "in" a different pubkey.

Comment: No, I sent funds to other address. Pubkey of first output got using sender address, and pubkey of second output with recepient address. The problem is if I will scan blockchain for transactions related to my address. How can I distinguish when I recepient or sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a transaction includes a key image in a ring which corresponds to one of the outputs you own, then it is a transaction you sent. If no key image in a tx corresponds, then it is not a transaction you sent. This holds regardless of whether any output is sent to your address. Usually, when you send money, there will be a change output back to you, but not always.

Comment: You means the key image which I get in *vin*?

Comment: Yes. spam for stupid mininum comment length.

Comment: OK. I will try.